# rm !(file name) is not working in ubuntu it showing error " bash: !: event not found"

Tags: bash, command

I am trying to remove all the files in a directory but keeping two files in this directory.

I used the command

```
rm !(1file name| 2filename)
```

But it throws error

```
bash: !: event not found
```

Please help me to correct the command.

Comment: Bash got contaminated by some garbage from a sea-shell.  Use [`set +H`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin) to cancel the expansion of history with exclamation marks.  That said, it isn't clear what you're trying to do — it looks suspiciously as though you'll exchange one error message for another if you use `set +H`.

Comment: "Contaminated" is a *bit* harsh.

Answer (score 5):

`!` attempts to expand history event. In BASH you can enable `extglob` using:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Then use this `rm` command to delete all but these 2 listed files:

```
rm !(@(filename1|filename2))
```

Comment: In extended globing it means one of the matches in given pattern using pipes.

Comment: Yes, the command rm !(@(filename1|filename2)) works. But before I were able to remove files using rm !(file name1| filename2) command.But yesterday only this command start to show this error.Any idea on this.

Comment: To make `!(file name1| filename2)` work you need to first do `set +H` to turn off history expansion.

Comment: why wrapping my rm !(... | ...) like `shopt -s extglob; rm !(*tar.gz|*.ini); shopt -u extglob;` does not work, claiming ! is still not known ?

Comment: What is your bash version? Are you sure you are in `bash`?